# Is this set up a reversible process and is the adiabatic equation of state applicable here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, reversibility, adiabatic

I had this question in a recent test:

[image]

My teacher while discussing this question used the adiabatic equation of state PV^gamma=constant to solve for length L (options C and D). And used work energy theorem to obtain the maximum kinetic energy (options A and B). While using work energy theorem, work done by atmosphere would be Patm(ΔV) and for work done by gas he used Δ(PV)/(gamma-1).

But aren't both of these formulae inapplicable for irreversible processes, and is the given process not irreversible? To the best of my understanding, it must be irreversible since the system is not in mechanical equilibrium at each time. Is there a method to solve this question considering the process to be irreversible? Thanks in advance

Comment: From which end is the potato fired (open or closed)?

Comment: The potato moves from closed end to the open end

Comment: Did your teacher make this problem up?

Comment: Though I cannot be sure, but i dont think he did, because I found a similar (or even the same) question on the internet, which use the same solution. Here are the links: https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-at/question/30-a-potato-gun-fires-a-potato-horizontally-down-a-halfopen-cylinder-of-crosssectional-area/

another website: https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer-physics/a-potato-gun-first-a-potato-horizontally-down-a-half-open-cylinder-of-cross-sectional-area-a-when-th-32499354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not solve homework and exercise questions on this site. So the following only speaks to some of the concepts you are questioning.

> But aren't both of these formulae inapplicable for irreversible
> processes, and is the given process not irreversible?

The formula

$$PV^{\gamma}=C$$

is for a *reversible* adiabatic process of an ideal gas. The process described (rapid piston movement) is an *irreversible* adiabatic process. The equation does not apply.

For the same reason, you cannot use the formula

$$\frac{\Delta (PV)}{1-\gamma}$$

for the work done in the work energy principle because it applies to reversible adiabatic work, not irreversible adiabatic work.

But the formula

$$P_{atm}\Delta V$$

Can be used because the external pressure can always be used to calculate the work. Only when the gas is in equilibrium can the gas pressure be used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I had thought the same. Could you also just hint me towards any possible ways I can explore to solve this question considering expansion to be irreversible?

Comment: Do you understand how the work energy principle applies here?

Comment: I think I do. Since no energy is being lost we are converting the work done by all the forces into the kinetic energy of bullet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement doesn't say anything about the mass of the potato.  If the mass of the potato is very high, then the gas will expand very slowly and approach reversible expansion.  Under these circumstances a maximum amount of work will be done by the gas on the potato, and its final kinetic energy will be maximum.  So your teacher's approach to getting maximum KE is correct.

Comment: But if the gas expands very slowly and the cylinder isn't insulated, how can the process be adiabatic as stated? Am I missing something?

Comment: Also it says $l<<L$ implying the volume of the potato is negligible compared to the volume of the cylinder. That wouldn't seem to square with the idea that the mass of the potato is very high.

Comment: I guess we have to agree to disagree.  The density of the potato can be very high.

Comment: OK, let that be the case. But the problem states: "the potato moves along the cylinder quickly enough so that no heat is transferred to the gas". If it moves quickly, then isn't the process irreversible?

Comment: Maybe quickly enough to be approximately adiabatic but not quickly enough to be irreversible.  In any event, the result in the limit of high mass is certainly going to provide an upper bound (maximum possible value) for the increase in kinetic energy of the potato.

Comment: In closing, can we agree that the wording of the problem leaves a lot to be desired?

Comment: I would have changed the wording slightly from "maximum kinetic energy" to "maximum possible kinetic energy."  Otherwise I have no problems with the wording.